# Grabbing values (Name, Address, Phone, etc.) from directory websites like TruePeopleSearch.com with Chrome Developer Tool

Tags: python, json, parsing, uri

Good day everybody.  I'm still learning parsing data with Python.  I'm now trying to familiarize myself with Chrome Developer Tools.  My question is when inspecting a directory website like TruePeopleSearch.com, how do I copy or view the variables that holds the data such as Name, Phone, and Address?  I tried browsing the tool, but since I'm new with the Developer tool, I'm so lost with all the data.  I would appreciate if the experts here points me to the right direction.

Thank you all!

Comment: if you mean information in HTML then there is no variables - it keeps all as tree with HTML and you can use `xpath` or `css` selectors to get it in Python modules like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`. And in DevTools you should have options (in context menu) `get xpath for selected element`

Comment: Yes I figured it's easier for me to just parse the data from the HTML body using BeautifulSoup than grabbing from JS paths.  Thanks Furas, I'm learning soup right now.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further navigating the Developer Console, I learned that these strings are located in these variables, by copying the JS paths.

## NAME & AGE

document.querySelector("#personDetails > div:nth-child(1)").innerText

## ADDRESS

document.querySelector("#personDetails > div:nth-child(4)").innerText

## PHONE NUMBERS

document.querySelector("#personDetails > div:nth-child(6)").innerText

## STEP 1

From the website, highlight are that you need to inspect and click "Inspect Element"

## STEP 2

Under elements, right-click the highlighted part and copy the JS path

## STEP 3

Navigate to console and paste the JS path and add .innerText and press Enter